# Mongoose nested arrays filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a schema in Mongo as follows:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73cbeb2258414c5d9bf2a5"),
"make" : {
    "name" : "Excel Boats",
    "models" : [
        {
            "year" : 2012,
            "name" : "1860V86",
            "subModels" : [
                {
                    "name" : "",
                    "controlNumber" : "OB1133079",
                    "protoTypeNumber" : "",
                    "status" : "A",
                    "classCode" : "OB",
                    "boatType" : "UT",
                    "powerType" : "OU",
                    "boatLength" : 18,
                    "horsePower" : 70,
                    "hullConstruction" : "A",
                    "msrp" : 9589,
                    "lowCostAmount" : 4700,
                    "highCostAmount" : 5270,
                    "retailAmount" : 6540,
                    "notes" : ""
                },
                {
                    "name" : "",
                    "controlNumber" : "OB1133080",
                    "protoTypeNumber" : "",
                    "status" : "A",
                    "classCode" : "OB",
                    "boatType" : "UT",
                    "powerType" : "OU",
                    "boatLength" : 18,
                    "horsePower" : 90,
                    "hullConstruction" : "A",
                    "msrp" : 10889,
                    "lowCostAmount" : 4900,
                    "highCostAmount" : 5970,
                    "retailAmount" : 6840,
                    "notes" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to filter the data so I can bring back the subModel that has an mrsp value of 9589 only. This is the code I have at the minute but it brings back an empty array for the subModels.

```
db.boats.aggregate({
      $match: {
        $and: [
          {'make.name': 'Excel Boats'},
          {'make.models.year': 2012},
          {'make.models.name': '1860V86'}
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        'make.models.subModels': {
          $filter: {
            input: '$make.models.subModels',
            as: 'subModel',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$subModel.msrp', 10889]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ).pretty()
```

This is the result when I run the query

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73cbeb2258414c5d9bf2a5"),
"make" : {
    "models" : [
        {
            "subModels" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

What I was hoping to get was this result

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c73cbeb2258414c5d9bf2a5"),
"make" : {
    "models" : [
        {
            "subModels" : [ {
                "name" : "",
                "controlNumber" : "OB1133079",
                "protoTypeNumber" : "",
                "status" : "A",
                "classCode" : "OB",
                "boatType" : "UT",
                "powerType" : "OU",
                "boatLength" : 18,
                "horsePower" : 70,
                "hullConstruction" : "A",
                "msrp" : 9589,
                "lowCostAmount" : 4700,
                "highCostAmount" : 5270,
                "retailAmount" : 6540,
                "notes" : ""
            } ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

If anyone can provide any information where I am going wrong I would much appreciate it. I have a feeling it has something to do with the nested array within an array, as I am able to grab the information within the models array with no issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Typo Errors in your query.

```
cond: {$eq: ['$$subModel.msrp', 9589]}
```

Comment: Oops, yeah there was a typo but even when corrected , it doesn't work, still returns the empty subModels. I have tried this with the other keys as well, like lowCostAmount, highCostAmount etc.